# Persisting IP after change when hostname called (Windows)

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns

I have a NAS running linux on my network and a PC running Windows 10.

Previously I had a 192.168.2.x network, however, because of some changes in the network I changed everything to 192.168.0.x.

So, the router, which is also the DHCP server, is 192.168.0.1, the NAS is 192.168.0.100 and the PC is 192.168.0.101.

However, the NAS is not accessible via hostname anymore. It can be accessed perfectly via IP (192.168.0.100), but not by its hostname. I've searched an applied some remedies apparently to the same problem, but they didn't work for me. The Windows hosts file does not contain any entry apart from 127.0.0.1. I've flushed the dns with ipconfig /flushdns, rebooted everything..., I've checked the adaptor IP4 configuration in Windows and everything is automatic, nothing manually set. But still when I ping the hostname of the NAS, it tries to get 192.168.2.100, instead the new address.

What can be failing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The Windows hosts file does not contain any entry apart from 127.0.0.1." - This is the problem, it should contain a entry, that assigns a hostname to `192.168.0.100`

Comment: Ok, but it does not contain the old entry either!! And the IP is set by DHCP. What if it changes?

Comment: If you attempt to ping the hostname, what ip address, does it attempt to contact?  Unless you have a DNS server or an active domain server you didn't mention, you being able to access the hostname of another PC, doesn't make sense.

Comment: If I try to ping the hostname right now, it tries to ping the old IP, 192.168.2.100. I have no other DNS but the router, and I have automatic DNS assignment in the adapter settings. :-?

Comment: Ok, thanks, @Ramhound, adding it to the hosts file it works now, but having the NAS assigned the IP via DHCP, wouldn't it stop working if it gets a different IP via DHCP?

Comment: The simplest solution is add the entry to the host file.  You can also reset the router if you want.  You don't indicate anything about your router though.  "but having the NAS assigned the IP via DHCP, wouldn't it stop working if it gets a different IP via DHCP?" DHCP isn't DNS.  Your NAS is automatically getting an IP address assigned to it, that doesn't mean, your DNS is automatically being updated.  I imagine none of your other hostnames are correct, but you didn't indicate that fact.

Comment: I've already rebooted the router, and the NAS and the PC... Everything. With no success. Answer the question if you fancy, so I can upvote it.

Comment: A simple reboot is not enough.  You would have to Reset the router to factory settings in order to clear the incorrect information.  You could I suppose, depending on the firmware, ssh into it and solved the problem that way.

Comment: Meh, that wouldn't work. I have a dumb-oriented router with no SSH access and really limited settings. But a freset sounds too hardcore to me right now. I think I'll try to live with the entry in the hosts file.